# Solve a system of complex equations and plot the solution

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I'm trying to solve a system of 2 equations with an unknown real parameter k0, the solution is complex. then I want to plot the obtained solution function of k0: here is my code: (I here is the complex number). Please I need your help
[image]

```
nm = 10^-9;
a = 10 nm;
d1 = 21 nm;
\[Omega]p = 17.2 10^15;
\[Gamma] = 0.0835 10^15;
c = 3 10^8;
\[Epsilon]0 = 2.25;
\[Alpha]1 = (5.45 - 0.73 \[Omega]p^2/((c k0)^2 + I c k0 \[Gamma]) - \[Epsilon]0)/(5.45 - 0.73 \[Omega]p^2/((k0)^2 + I c k0 \[Gamma]) + 2 \[Epsilon]0)a^3;
\[Alpha] = (k0^2 \[Alpha]1)/(6 \[Pi] \[Epsilon]0);
d = k0 d1;
 L = 3 d^-3 (PolyLog[3, E^(I (\[Beta] - 1) d)] + PolyLog[3, E^(-I (\[Beta] - 1) d)] - I d (PolyLog[2, E^(I (\[Beta]- 1) d)] + PolyLog[2, E^(-I (\[Beta] - 1) d)])) - \[Alpha]^-1 == 0;

T = -((3 d^-3)/2) (PolyLog[3, E^(I (\[Beta] - 1) d)] + PolyLog[3, E^(-I (\[Beta] - 1) d)] - 
   I d (PolyLog[2, E^(I (\[Beta] - 1) d)] + PolyLog[2, E^(-I (\[Beta] - 1) d)]) - d^2 (PolyLog[1, E^(I (\[Beta] - 1) d)] + PolyLog[1, E^(-I (\[Beta] - 1) d)])) - \[Alpha]^-1 == 0;
 Plot[Re[Solve[T&&L,\[Beta]]], {k0, 300, 700}]
 Plot[Im[Solve[T&&L,\[Beta]]], {k0, 300, 700}]
```

Comment: Solve is not able to solve your equations.

Comment: Hi daniel, do you have an idea how to solve those equations. Many thanks

Comment: Which parameter range of `\[Beta]` you expect?

Comment: I have no clear cut answer, I can only speculate. Could be that there is no closed form solution? Anyway, can you not try to give a value to k0 and  solve the equations numerically to get at least an idea what is going on. If you can calculate a solution for different values of k0, you may be able to fit a function to the obtained values.

Comment: There are **Four** equations but only three variables `Re[β]`,`Im[β]`,`k0`, so the equations is over-determinated.

Comment: @cvmgt what about if I take only one of those equations (i take only T equation for example), is it possible to sokve it? Thanks